# How to implement data structures like stack/queue in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

How can I simulate the behavior of a stack or a queue in VHDL? Any pointers?

I had thought of using some thing like logical shift operation of bits but how to check the constraints of stack being empty or the case of stack overflow?

Comment: You ask how to "simulate the behavior". Do you want to write synthesizable code (that goes to hardware), or do you want code for your simulation. That makes a big difference in which VHDL constructs you can use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start by reading Peter Ashenden book "The Designer's Guide to VHDL".
On chapter 19 he implements a Queuing Network and he goes at length to explain how to implement queues on VHDL.
You can get the VHDL files for that book at: http://www.csee.umbc.edu/help/VHDL/ashenden/ch_19/

Answer (score 3):

You will want to implement a FIFO if you are working in VHDL/Verilog.  If this is going to be instantiated in an actual FPGA, you will model the FIFO with read and write pointers to block ram in the FPGA.  Check out a well-developed implementation at OpenCores...

http://opencores.org/project,versatile_fifo

Answer (score 1):

Don't implement a stack.  Use the FPGA vendor's core.

Comment: I'd argue against using vendor's cores. Inferred logic has the potential to be just as efficient as a vendor core. It also allows makes your design technology independent, giving you the choice to switch FPGA vendors or target different ASIC technologies.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a RAM Component and use it as FIFO, LIFO or every kind of data structure you want.

if you need a Stack, after making RAM Component don't use Address bus for it, make a variable which contain Top Of Stack address. then with POP decrease it (first send the output to Data Bus) and with PUSH increase it (then save the input to TOS[top of stack] Variable).

if you need more I can tell you more...